# How to solve the 'mul objective has no attribute 'cos' '

Tags: python, sympy

How to solve the multi object problem?

```
import sympy as sym
from sympy import lambdify

x = sym.Symbol('x')
n = sym.Symbol('n')
f = sym.sin(n*x)

derivative_f = f.diff(x)
derivative_f = lambdify(x, derivative_f)

x = float(input('x:'))
print(derivative_f(x))
print(derivative_f)
```

If I input 2, the expected result should be `2*cos(2*x)`.

Comment: Please show the complete traceback of the error you get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code contains a few misconceptions. One problem is an important general programming rule: try to use different variable names for variables with different meanings. So, `x` shouldn't be assigned a float, as it was a symbolic variable before.  And `derivative_f` being a symbolic expression, shouldn't be assigned the result of `lambdify`.

Note that `sympy`'s symbolic world doesn't mix well with the numeric world of non-sympy functions. `lambdify` forms a bridge between these worlds, from completely symbolic to completely numeric. E.g. the function created with `lambdify` doesn't have access to the symbolic `n` anymore.

The code `lambdify(x, derivative_f)` contains an error. `derivative_f` is a symbolic expression containing two symbolic variables (`x` and `n`), so it needs to be called as `derivative_f_x_n = lambdify((x, n), derivative_f)` (also giving the result a different name). Afterwards, you can use numeric expressions as `derivative_f_x_n(7, 8)`, but you can't use symbolic parameters anymore.

For what you seem to be trying to do, `lambdify` isn't adequate. To get the derivative with `x` substituted, you call `.subs(x, new_value)` directly on the symbolic version of `derivative_f`:

```py
import sympy as sym
from sympy import lambdify

x = sym.Symbol('x')
n = sym.Symbol('n')
f = sym.sin(n * x)

derivative_f_x = f.diff(x)

x_float = 2.0
print(derivative_f_x.subs(x, x_float))
```

Output: `n*cos(2.0*n)`

Also note that sympy strongly prefers to work with exact symbolic expressions, and using floats inevitably brings in approximations.  Whenever possible, integers, sympy fractions (`sym.S(1)/2`) or symbolic expressions (`sym.sqrt(5)`) are recommended.

You call also use the derivative with respect to `x` and then substitute `n`:

```py
print(f.diff(x).subs(n, 2))
```

Output: `2*cos(2*x)`

To use that function later on in numeric calculations, after substitution you only have one symbolic variable left(`x`):

```py
g = lambdify(x, f.diff(x).subs(n, 2))
```

You can type `help(g)` to see its generated source code:

```
    Source code:
    
    def _lambdifygenerated(x):
        return (2*cos(2*x))
```

Then you can use `g` e.g. to create matplotlib plot. After `lambdify` nothing is symbolic anymore.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

xs = np.linspace(0, 10)
plt.plot(xs, g(xs))
```

[image: plot of the derivative]

Comment: thank you for your detail explanation, your suggestion does help me to improve my python skill.  Now it will be better to use subs. to keep the variable, or use lambdify to find the numerical answer.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer hit the key point, that you needed to account for the symbolic `n` when lambdifying.

Look at the help of your function:

```
In [2]: help(derivative_f)

Help on function _lambdifygenerated:

_lambdifygenerated(x)
    Created with lambdify. Signature:
    ....
    Source code:
    
    def _lambdifygenerated(x):
        return (n*cos(n*x))
```

It's a function of `x`, drawing `n` from the global environment, here a symbol.

The full error message when given an array argument:

```
In [5]: derivative_f(np.array([.1,.2,.3]))
AttributeError: 'Mul' object has no attribute 'cos'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-5-e04e9f3c0a8e>", line 1, in <module>
    derivative_f(np.array([.1,.2,.3]))
  File "<lambdifygenerated-1>", line 2, in _lambdifygenerated
    return (n*cos(n*x))
TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type Mul which has no callable cos method
```

See the `return` line in the traceback.  That's the 'source code' in the help, and tells you what `numpy` is trying to execute.

test the inner expression of that line:

```
In [6]: n*np.array([.1,.2,.3])
Out[6]: array([0.1*n, 0.2*n, 0.3*n], dtype=object)
```

This is an object dtype array.  Math on such an array delegates the calculation to each of the elements.  Specifically it tries

```
(0.1*n).cos()
```

`0.1*n` is a sympy `mul` expression, hence the error.  `symbols` often don't work in `numpy` expressions.

`lambdify` is a handy way of creating `numpy` functions from `sympy` expressions, but it needs to be used with care, and full awareness of what it does, and does not, do.